# Can GCC version script include debug symbols?

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

When building a shared library with GCC, without using a version script, we can split our debug symbols into separate .dbg files, allowing us to debug into crash dumps.

```
objcopy --only-keep-debug foo.so foo.dbg
objcopy --strip-unneeded foo.so
objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=foo.dbg foo.so
```

Now, we're exploring using the `--version-script` option to only export the public functions of our library

```
{
    global:
        extern "C" {
            fooInterface*;
        };
    local: *;
};
```

However, this appears to hide *all* the symbols (except fooInterface()), including dynamic and static debug symbols.

In many ways this is what we want, but is there any way to get the best of both worlds? Is it possible to end up with a shared library that only exports the public functions, while still being able to debug into crash dumps with a separate .dbg file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to end up with a shared library that only exports the public functions, while still being able to debug into crash dumps with a separate .dbg file?

The linker version script (it's not a GCC version script) is *completely* orthogonal to having debug info.

That is: the *exact same solution* should work: link `foo.so` with the version script, then use `objcopy` to save debug info and remove unneeded symbols.

I just tested this on a trivial example, and it works:

```
$ cat foo.c
int bar()
{
  return 42;
}

int fooInterface()
{
  return bar();
}

$ gcc -g -fPIC -shared -o foo.so foo.c -Wl,--version-script=foo.lds 
$ objcopy --only-keep-debug foo.so foo.dbg
$ objcopy --strip-unneeded foo.so
$ objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=foo.dbg foo.so
```

Observe that only `fooInterface` is exported from `foo.so`:

```
$ nm foo.so | grep ' T '
nm: foo.so: no symbols
$ nm -D foo.so | grep ' T '
0000000000001100 T fooInterface
```

Observe that GDB has no trouble loading *full* symbols for `foo.so`:

```
$ gdb -q ./foo.so
Reading symbols from ./foo.so...
Reading symbols from /tmp/vs/foo.dbg...    <<<=== Note

(gdb) info func bar
All functions matching regular expression "bar":

File foo.c:
1:      int bar();
```

If above example doesn't work for you, you probably have a buggy version of GDB or binutils.

If the example works, but your real library doesn't, then you are probably making a mistake somewhere during your build process.

Comment: I've just tested this, and confirmed that it does in fact just work. There must have been some other instability present when we first implemented this that prevented the .dbg file from getting to the right location.